Missing icons in shell menu after update
I'm on ubuntu 22.04 and I just updated my system. After reboot I noticed that the top right menu of my shell is missing some icons.
Here's a picture of the menu in question
I'm using the Graphite-gtk-theme but I don't think the problem is related to this particular theme because changing it doesn't resolve the problem.
What can I do?
